# Number of dimension of function learned by a neural netowrk

Tags: neural-network

A neural network can be considered as a function, let's say a function *f: R<sup>n</sup> -> R<sup>m</sup>*. I was wondering: what are the values of *n* and *m*?

Are they the number of input and output neurons? Or is it related to the number of weights learned by the neural network?

Answer (score 1):

n is the number of inputs, m is the number of outputs. Generally corresponding to the number of neurons in the first / last layer.